# Applying Styles in media queries which has same width but different height

Tags: html, css

So I am facing problem  with where I have 2 different mediaqueries where the width is same for each but the height is different like this:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width:1920px) and (min-height:1080px){
           #home{
              height:1080px;
               }
     }
       @media only screen and (max-width:1920px) and (min-height:1200px){
           #home{
              height:1200px;
               }
     }
```

But what happens is that when I change the screen dimensions to 1920px width with 1200px height it seems that this media query is not overriding the other one with a height of 1080px. For now I am stuck here and cant figure out the mistake I made. Whats the issue here ? Where am I going wrong ? what is the solution to this problem ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: It looks all correct to me, what if you try a different style for debugging i.e. #home {color:red;border:1px solid red;} rather than height, so you can see it clearly.

Comment: Well I tried it but still no hope. Do you think there is some other mediaquery thats messing around ?

Comment: That sounds possible, be sure to follow the rule, big number to small for max-, and small to big for min-, the above rules look fine.

Comment: @sdcr the problem is actually with the height, the other things are fine like `color` etc. they are good the only thing that I am not able to manipulate is the height.

Comment: What is the reason to set the `height` values? you can also try `min-height` if you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

The world 'screen' in the media queries is a little bit confusing. The actual meaning of it is not the computer screen resolution but the actual internal size of the browser window. Even when the window is maximized, to compute the actual height you should discount from the screen height the browser window caption address bar, system tray, etc., so if the screen resolution is 1200px then media query screen size will be something about 1180px.

The following code sample illustrates the concept. See it in full screen mode, try to resize the browser window and see how the color changes:

```css
body{
  background-color: yellow;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:1920px) and (min-height:500px){
  body{
    background-color: lime;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:1920px) and (min-height:800px){
  body{
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```